# Rails - pull attribute value from table using two conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, model-view-controller, querying

I have two tables in my rails application: a user table and an activity table. The user has many activities. Right now, I am trying to find out how to print out the activity_name where the activity_type = :personal AND where user_id = current_user.id.

In my activities index file i have the following:

```
<% @activities.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:activity_type => :personal).each do |activity| %>
<%= activity.activity_name %>
<% end %>
```

Nothing prints out on the page - I definitely have added users and activities to the database, as I have checked the rails consoler. Have I set up the each do loop incorrectly? Is there a different way to query this data?

Answer (score 0):

It should be written this way:

```
<% @activities.where(user_id: current_user.id, activity_type: "personal").each do |activity| %>
  <%= activity.activity_name %>
<% end %>
```

---

Or better than this, since the user `has_many` activities:

```
<% current_user.activities.where(activity_type: "personal").each do |activity| %>
  <%= activity.activity_name %>
<% end %>
```

---

We can compact it even more using scopes:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.personal
    where(activity_type: "personal")
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```
def index # or whatever you wnat
  @activities = current_user.activities.personal
end
```

The view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= activity.activity_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to the following and still nothing prints out on the view. Are there any reasons as to why this may be happening?                          <% @activities.where(user_id: current_user.id, activity_type: :personal).each do |activity| %>
            <h4><%= activity.activity_name %></h4>
            <% end %>

Comment: from where is coming `@activities` ?

Comment: from my activities controller : class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.all
    end

Comment: Are you sure there are activities in your database? Open the rails console: `rails console` from your `terminal` and type `Activity.count`

Comment: Okay if your remove the `where` conditions does it show the 10 acitivties?

Comment: Then there no acitivities with `id = current_user.id` or no ones with `activity_type = 'personal'` or both. You can check each condition alone to figure it out.

Comment: I've tried them both separately and neither work - I know from looking at the objects in the rails console that there are definitely activities with id = current_user.id and activity_type = 'personal'

Comment: From your console what gives you this `Activity.where(activity_type: 'personal')`

Comment: This is what I get:   irb(main):003:0> Activity.where(activity_type: 'personal')
  Activity Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."activity_type" = ?  [["activity_type", 0]]

Comment: I mean are there any record found?

Comment: I got it - it wasn't recognising this in my activities ruby class: enum activity_type: {personal: 1, physical: 2, community: 3}. So I changed my query from using the enum category names to using the numbers and now it is displaying the correct information. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an activity association for users you should be able to do something like

```
current_user.activities.where(activity_type: :personal)
```